# Qual melhor maneira de criar um app que funcione offline e sincronize dados com servidor?

Tags: android, mysql, delphi, integração

Estou me aprofundando no mundo *Mobile*, onde tive o primeiro desafio, que é criar um *App* Android de cadastro básico, nome, idade, etc. O complicado (pelo menos pra mim) é que tenho que atualizar esses dados salvos no SQLite do Android para uma BD MySQL no servidor.

Estou utilizando a ferramenta RAD Studio XE8.

Alguém teria uma luz de como faço isso? Tenho que habilitar algum serviço por fora, ou deixar um aplicativo Windows rodando para fazer a integração?
O meu objetivo é realizar de uma maneira simples que, ao clicar em um botão sincronizar, o registro seja guardado no BD do servidor, e outro botão para limpar os dados.

Obrigado.

Comment: Não cheguei a usar o Delphi para desenvolvimento para Android ainda, mas eu recomendo que envie requisições para Scripts (PHP ou outra linguagem de script) no seu servidor. Então estes scripts poderiam realizar as alterações em banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método que eu sugiro é o seguinte. Supondo que você possa utilizar uma linguagem de scripts no seu servidor, primeiro carregue os dados do Banco Local na aplicação Delphi (Android).

Para prosseguir, adicione a biblioteca Indy HTTP e a Classes do sistema:

```
uses Classes, IdHTTP;
```

Crie as variáveis necessárias:

```
var 
    ParamList : TStringList; // Lista para representar o registro do banco
    MyRow     : TWhatever; // Esta variável hipotética representa o objeto ou array onde você terá o registro do Banco Local
    HTTP      : TIdHTTP; // Objeto HTTP do Indy
```

Coloque os dados que devem ser passados ao servidor (único registro de tabela) em um `TStringList` no formato padrão de URIs:

```
ParamList.Add('id=' + MyRow.ID);
ParamList.Add('name=' + MyRow.Nome);
ParamList.Add('phone_number=' + MyRow.PhoneNumber);
// Adicione todos os campos da tabela.
```

Após, você deve criar o objeto HTTP do Indy e realizar o POST para o Script no servidor:

```
HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
    HTTP.Post('http://ip-ou-nome-do-servidor/pasta/do/script', ParamList);
finally
    HTTP.Free;
    ParamList.Free;
end;
```

O exemplo acima enviaria os dados Nome, Sobrenome e ID a um script no servidor (possivelmente em PHP ou outra linguagem que você prefira, conheça ou queira aprender). Este script por sua vez iria realizar as operações sobre o Banco Remoto (Servidor).

Este é claramente apenas um exemplo genérico e ilustrativo. Contém os conceitos base para o método.

Se não tiver conhecimento sobre algum dos termos acima, sugiro que estude:

- HTTP
- POST e GET
- Scripts CGI

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o que é difícil na sua pergunta é mais em relaçao às tantas formas que o Delphi permite fazer, que escolher a melhor depende realmente de cada particularidade.

Por exemplo, no delphi é muito simples conectar com DataSnap e tem um monte de tutoriais no YOUTUBE ensinando a implementar tanto o lado servidor como o cliente.
De uma estudada em JSON que,na minha opinião, é a melhor saída para a parte de envio de informações para o servidor.
Já para recuperar a informação, confie nos DatasetProvider-->ClientDataset

O Firedac também tem uma série de novidades, como por exemplo os componentes ETL, que permitem sincronizar tabelas de bancos de dados diferentes, e um recurso fatástico que talvez seja suficiente para ti: Trabalhar com o banco offline.

Eu recomendo os cursos do DEVMEDIA, especialmente do professor Guinter Pauling, especialista nestes assuntos.

Se voce tiver um servidor REST para consumir, ai o Delphi tem também excelentes controles de conexao, e eu recomendo começar pelo restDebuger, que vem com o delphi.

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia usar a tecnologia **DataSnap REST** com uso de objetos em JSON da própria Embarcadero, que o mesmo faz as sincronizações entre Cliente/Servidor tornando o tempo de resposta muito mais rápido e o componente FireDac para fazer conexão com banco de dados para o Mobile Android e MySQL, a tecnologia já está pronta para funcionar em modo offline assim ela não ficaria o tempo todo online, somente quando for fazer uma sincronização. Se você não tem conhecimento sobre essa nova tecnologia sugiro que você dê uma olhada no tutorial que o Adriano Santos fez.

[TDevRocks DataSnap REST](http://www.tdevrocks.com.br/2014/10/31/tutorial-criando-meu-app-step-by-step-datasnap-rest-parte-vi/)